# importing *.js from external domain not working in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I have import an js file from our another domain by using the following code

```
<script src="http://webiduga.com/myJs.js"></script>
```

Which consists solely of:

```
 var a = 'Testing';
```

Then append that content to an existing div in the current html page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.alert.alert-quiz').html(a);

});
```

This code works great in Safari and IE, but it does not work in FF and Chrome.  Do you have any idea why?  The code is simple but it derived me crazy the last 2 hours.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `$(document).ready()`? If the code is simple, please post it.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why that wouldn't work in some browsers but not others. Use the debugging tools in the browsers. Are there any errors in the JS console? Do you see the scripts being loaded (with the right and complete content) in the Net tab?

Comment: While I'm not an expert on the subject, I strongly suspect this has to do with some browsers being more restrictive on cross-domain scripting and would start investigating there.

Comment: @smclark89 I thought there might be some security issues that I do not know.  So, you guys think this code (importing js from external domain) should simply work in all browsers?

Comment: @erkaner are you allowed to post the link to the JS file so we can test it out?

Comment: @AlbertXing  I updated the code, the url is available now.

Comment: There are no cross-origin restrictions on simply loading a script. JSON-P — the pre-CORS work-around for the same origin policy — depends on that!

Comment: @erkaner Everything works for me, I can write `alert(a)` after the script import. Make sure your script tag comes after the one with the URL.

Comment: @Quentin After some quick reading, I'm pretty sure you're right. On a different note, this SO question appears to be addressing the OP's issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864732/javascript-accessing-variables-defined-in-external-js-files

Comment: Maybe, just MAYBE, the docready is triggering faster than the file download from your other domain?

Comment: Why don't you use `innerText` instead since it is a text string?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL — impossible, script elements are blocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mockup for you and it's working for me in IE, Chrome, FF, Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://webiduga.com/myJs.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.alert').html(a);

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span class="alert"></span>
</body>
```

I am not sure what the `.alert-quiz` is for but does it matter if you leave it out?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe `$('.alert.alert-quiz').html('a');`? I'm not sure, I'm a rookie :S

Comment: `.html('a')` will make the content be the string `a`.

Comment: I think the `.alert.alert-quiz` was causing a confusion so I removed the second "class" definition and it worked fine in my solution.