# Accessing a variable obtained by user from separate file in JS

Tags: javascript, html, variables

A beginner question:

I'd like to create an app where I obtain an imaginary number from user and plot it to complex plane. Since I'm hoping to add other things later, I keep the code in separate files, connected in HTML file.

In first file, I get the real and the complex part from the user:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button-number").click(function() {
    var realPart = prompt("Please, enter the real Part of the number:")
    var imagPart = prompt("Please, enter the imaginary Part of the number:")
});})
```

which I use in the second file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var c = document.getElementById("ComplexPlane");
var number = c.getContext("2d");
number.beginPath();
number.arc(500+50*realPart,300-50*imagPart,10,0,2*Math.PI);
number.stroke();
number.fill();})
```

However, this doesn't work. It works if I define the variables manually outside the function. I'm not entirely sure how are all the operations timed, since my variables aren't defined when the document loads. I'd love to know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Try using a module loading system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Accessing Variables Defined in External .js files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864732/javascript-accessing-variables-defined-in-external-js-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected.

Instead using global variable scope you could use localStorage

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

you can store the real an imaginary part numbers in localStorage in your first file. And you can access them in your second file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this solution for now since it's the easier one.

Answer (score 0):

I this what your trying to do?

```
$("#button-number").click(function() {
  var realPart = prompt("Please, enter the real Part of the number:")
  var imagPart = prompt("Please, enter the imaginary Part of the number:")
  if (realPart != null && imagPart != null) {
    var c = document.getElementById("ComplexPlane");
    var number = c.getContext("2d");
    number.beginPath();
    number.arc(parseInt(realPart),parseInt(imagPart),10,0,2*Math.PI);
    number.stroke();
  } 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LeroyRon/93jvtrae/
Or part of what your doing...
realPart and imagPart could be set in a global scope or storage.

Comment: Yes, but the difference being that the code for drawing is in a separate file.